# Check if number is in specific range

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am making a numbers game.

If you input a number from 1-5 (1, 2, 3, 4 and 5)

It will display a text.

I tried tried doing something like this:

```
if (numbers == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5)
{
    std::cout << "TEXT";
}
```

(didnt work)

but is there an better way to put in a range of integers?

Comment: What about using `<` and `>` operators instead? I.e. `if (numbers >= 1 && numbers <= 5) ...`?

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted, equivalent to:

```
if ((numbers == 1) || (2) || (3) || (4) || (5))
{
    std::cout << "TEXT";
}
```

It won't work, because the expressions `2`, `3`, `4` and `5` are always not 0, they will always be `true`, and the `if` statement will only determine if `numbers` is 1.

I think you want to write it like this:

```
if (numbers == 1 || numbers == 2 || numbers == 3 || numbers == 4 || numbers == 5)
{
    std::cout << "TEXT";
}
```

And then an easier, cleaner way:

```
if (numbers >= 1 && numbers <= 5)
{
    std::cout << "TEXT";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides @Sprite's answer, following works too:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int valid[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int number = 5;

    if (std::any_of(std::begin(valid), std::end(valid), [number](auto i) { return i == number; })) {
        std::cout << "Valid number " << number << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Invalid number " << number << std::endl;
    }

    number = 6;

    if (std::any_of(std::begin(valid), std::end(valid), [number](auto i) { return i == number; })) {
        std::cout << "Valid number " << number << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Invalid number " << number << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Read about [`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEAGYArKS3oAMnlqYAcsYBGmYiABspAA6oFQnVaPUMTcyt/QLU6e0cXI3dPHyUVGNoGAmZiAlDjU0tFZUxVYMzsgjjnNw9vRSycvPDChQbKh2rE2q8ASkVUA2JkDgByKTMHZEMsAGpxMx11VuJMZiN57HEABgBBccnpzDmFtmASQgR1s03d7Z2HAhmjZgcIHrvxAHZZXZm/mYeMwAbmw8OhxBZZBYACJzb4zTikGaSJFmJG8GYWOHQ%2BY/Hb/AH0Ga0GrEY6wiy4j6/f54KgzCCtdAgEAiACeAH1UFRGQRmSB3MBXiDWGC%2BjMmSybBARWKkRDpCSusQIdCIMwDEQAT04dIZisCINaADyfNYUqkrjsT0dV88QSCZKUANHvMdG65pJJAA1UHoYmkz2SY7uhYB5Uhj1OmysKk0v5fWHKJS6u4O/5OtCayNhqSSACStFl/otHiDOZ04aSFYlfKl2ljZnt/0T1Px/1LZLNMy8cb28YB9N5/PZXJ5TsFwr94uj2hl0/lkM7qvVmtQ2t1%2BswhuIxrwprM5tJVsTNtTA8dded2bdHrzvtFJcDeZrnZrs/QjebCc%2BSdYKbtNN01rfks1dBY7y9QtiyrMsX1vMM3wQysPy/ICfxxAcDSNGYtj7RMRj6VgQBGCwRlIUwRi2cjUBI90ZDkCUBiGI5xk4ciCBI6ibVIABrbxJAAOi2AAOETPk%2BSQRO4CwAE4LDRYiRm4cjKOo0haJGciFBALZSE4qjCNIOBYBgRBnSMXw8HYMgKAgNBLOs2pgE4LYUSoayCA8HSIFcLjyNcBxsjZfzSAcowtAIAB5WhWBCwzSCwZ5RHYUL8BWUogUwHSEswAAPEpNVGdSHmUULRVcYhgr0LASPY/TiDwIw6qMmh6CYNgOB4fhBGEUQUDkOQhDwVwdMgPpUF8dIcoAWhmpkzQkBiZE4T5tOKUoNAgGwmlMREbCqBIkkEKIgjoXaToCM7aEO0lBFSEp0nKRp9Hye6NqetpbuVe62guxFWgqb7js4PoFGY4YuCIkiyIo0LNLykSvBmrxuBmYBkGQBEtkE4MIFwQgSE9MxERmPRHJs4nQbJwaZA4/yeP4iw9KUlTSGa5m4YSzTtN0/SGeMsyICQF1fE1chKAcqybMETB8CITxETaxgWFS7qAHcqt8FrodI1T4ZItiZnVi4ZkR5HUfRzHsdx%2BnDJ4hBViwTw3iEEi2Y5vS1Jokjeb0gzuL6fizE%2BQTZM4TgvU%2BTgLG4LZuE%2BN2RjMfXud9/n7d1yRU/UnmM8D0gsuIQING4IA%3D%3D%3D)